# What does the "A type used from another type must be public" error mean?

Tags: .net, types, public, delphi-prism

Delphi Prism for .NET:

For some of my member functions, I am getting an error, "A type used from another type must be public."

For instance, take a look at some of my member functions that are raising the error.

```
method ConnectTest(x,y,pg:integer):TConnection; virtual; <---error - TConnection must be public
method Addtheobject(co:TControlObject); <--- TControlObject must be public
method ClearCache(cc:TCacheType); <--- TCacheType must be public
```

All these methods are from within a class under public access specifier.

So, why are they raising this error?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `public` method that returns a type `T` or has a parameter of a type `T`, then `T` must also be `public`. Otherwise, the situation could easily arise where your method could be called, but its arguments couldn't be supplied, or its return value couldn't be stored/inspected/etc.

Comment: @ delve ohhhh Now I see my problem....Sometimes when you keep staring at the computer screen all day like a zombie typing away, you tend to forget things. thanks.